# Calling a Cocos2dx plugin function from JNICALL?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I have a `JNIEXPORT` void `JNICALL` function in `C++` that acts as a callback from my `Java` code. Upon the `Java` alerting the `C++` code that something has occurred, I want to call one of my `C++` functions that is in the same file.

But the `JNICALL` has a different scope, I assume, as my code is crashing when I try to make that call. (I get "accessed stale local reference" `JNI` error)

From most of the examples I've seen, the `JNICALL` function triggers a `JNI` call to a `Java` function, which I already know how to do.

But how would I make a `C++` function call from inside the `JNIEXPORT` function?

EDIT:
I should note that I believe this is more closely related to trying to call a Cocos2dx plugin based on my debugging.

```
void MyClass::myFunction(const char* param)
{
    CCLOG("Got into myFunction");
    PluginParam pParam(param);
    _plugin->CallFuncWithParam("passParam", &pParam, NULL);
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_package_Class_gotParam(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring param)
{
    CCLOG("Got into param callback");
    const char* nativeStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(param, NULL);
    MyClass class;
    class.myFunction(nativeStr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(param, nativeStr);
}
```

I'm able to see my debug outputs but it crashes on the callFuncWithParam line.

Comment: Post the actual code, for both the C++ function you're trying to call and the native method that's calling it.  And note that your "stale local reference" error is something that happens when you call a JNI API function that expects an object reference as an argument.

Comment: As a workaround I decided to just make `JNI` calls inside the `JNICALL` directly to the Java lib I'm using since the Cocos2dx plugin way wasn't working for whatever reason. In principle this would be the same as how Cocos accesses the Java, just not as pretty as their PluginProtocol wrappers.